# issues while implementing 2d graphs (bar charts, Pie diagrams etc) in an Android application

Tags: android, graph, offline, offline-mode

I am facing some issues while implementing 2d graphs in an Android application. The application should work in offline mode and the application shouldn't communicate to any servers. So we can't use any apis to implement the graph.

We are using sql lite database to save data. The application have an interface to accept data and save it in the DB. In the report section we are generating graphs based on the data in the DB.

Now are using a library named "achartengine" for this purpose. But we are facing some problem to customize it as per the client's design. We need to implement three graphs. Two bar graphs and one pie chart. We have almost  implemented the 2d version of the graphs but we couldn't able to write numbers inside the graphs.  Which is the better method to implement the graph? Please advice

Looking forward to your response.